# How to substitute for the variables in $f^{-1}$ of $f(x,y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

By the horizontal line test I think that I can tell $f(x,y)=x^{2}+y^{2}-1$ is not supposed to have an inverse function, however the screenshot that I have added shows two inverse functions $ f^{-1}= \pm \sqrt{x-y^{2}+1} $. When this function just maps to $0$ how am I supposed to substitute that number into the inverse function?

Example: with $x=2$ in the function $ f(x) =2x $ the outcome equals $4$, then $f^{-1}(x) = \dfrac{x}{2}$ and I use the y-value of 4 to retrieve the corresponding x-value.

[Wolframalpha.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuGVo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $x$ in $\pm\sqrt{x+y^2-1}$ is misleading.

In fact $f:\mathbb R^2\mapsto\mathbb R$ gives $f(x,y)=k$, so the inverse $f^{-1}:\mathbb R\mapsto\mathbb R^2$ takes $k$ and gives $(x,y)$.

For each $k\ge 1$ we have $f^{-1}(k)$ is a set of $2$D-points representing a circle, not just one couple of $(x,y)$ values.

What Wolfram is giving you is not $f^{-1}$ but the inverse of $g_y=f(\cdot,y)$

- Since $g_y(x)=f(x,y)=k\iff x^2+y^2-1=k\iff x^2=k-y^2+1\iff x=\pm\sqrt{k-y^2+1}$

Thus $g_y^{-1}(k)=\pm\sqrt{k-y^2+1}$.

$k$ being a "dummy" name, we can also say $g_y^{-1}(x)=\pm\sqrt{x-y^2+1}$, but this is not the "same" $x$ as the one in $f(x,y)$. This is why it largely misleading to use $x$, and $f^{-1}$ in this context.

- You could also be interested in $h_x=f(x,\cdot)$ or $h_x(y)=f(x,y)$ and $h_x^{-1}(k)=\pm\sqrt{k-x^2+1}$.

In each case, this gives two inverse functions:

$g_y^{-1}(k)$ takes $(y,k)$ as input and gives $\pm x$ in return.

$h_x^{-1}(k)$ takes $(x,k)$ as input and gives $\pm y$ in return.

Answer (score 0):

In the first place you should not think that the function $$f:\quad{\mathbb R}^2\to{\mathbb R},\qquad(x,y)\mapsto f(x,y):=x^2+y^2-1$$
has an inverse. Note that $f$ has at all points $(x,y)$ of the circle $x^2+y^2=R^2$ the same value $R^2-1$. For the existence of an inverse function you need the injectivity of $f$.

For a "simple" map $f:\>{\mathbb R}^2\to Y$ with an inverse $f^{-1}$ the range $Y$ should be two-dimensional as well. This means that your $f$ should have two components $f_1$ and $f_2$ as follows:
$${\bf f}=(f_1,f_2):\quad{\mathbb R}^2\to{\mathbb R}^2,\qquad(x,y)\mapsto\left\{\eqalign{u&=f_1(x,y)\cr v&=f_2(x,y)\cr}\right.\quad.$$
Note that the coordinate variables in the image space are called $u$, $v$ here. The inverse map ${\bf g}:={\bf f}^{-1}$ would then have two components $g_1$ and $g_2$, whereby
$${\bf g}=(g_1,g_2):\quad{\mathbb R}^2\to{\mathbb R}^2,\qquad(u,v)\mapsto\left\{\eqalign{x&=g_1(u,v)\cr y&=g_2(u,v)\cr}\right.\quad.$$
The variables $x$ and $y$ **do not occur** in the domain of ${\bf g}:={\bf f}^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you very much @christianblatter